# Reinterpreting Pointers in Julia

Tags: python, c++, julia

I have some C++ code that has existing python bindings, and I am trying to graft it on to Julia using PyCall.  One of the functions that gets called generates a pointer to a 2D array in memory to which I would like to wrap a Julia array around so that I can add/subtract/multiply by scalars, etc.   I know the size of the array, and it's currently represented as a PyObject to which I can do `x_ptr[1]`, `x_ptr[2]` and get correct values out.  But I'd like to have an array, `x`.

Comment: Try `?unsafe_wrap`.

Comment: What would I pass for the argument ``pointer::Ptr{T}``?  The data I'm interested in are doubles.

Comment: You would pass the address of the first element.  But I don't think you actually have a pointer, which is causing some confusion.  You have a `PyObject` that contains a pointer.  To use `unsafe_wrap`, you need the memory address of the block of memory.  Alternatively, you could look into wrapping the `PyObject` in a  `PyArray` — which uses the NumPy array interface and Julia's abstract array infrastructure to make it work like a Julian array.

Comment: So I have my  pointer, ``x``, I know  it's 9 double preicions elements, and I can dereference it as  ``x[1]`` as mentioned. it's clearly a ``PyCall.PyObject`` But If I try ``unsafe_wrap(A, x, (9,1)), I get  
```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching unsafe_wrap(::Array{Float64,1}, ::PyCall.PyObject, ::Tuple{Int64,Int64})
```

Comment: That's because `x` **isn't a pointer**.  You need to figure out how to get the memory address — just an unsigned integer — from your python object.  Without more details from you about the python side, I don't think anyone here can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example using numpy [array interface](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html). By default, PyCall converts numpy arrays to Julia's arrays, but we can prevent that with `@pycall` and the `::Any` annotation to show how you'd do it manually. You need to dig into the object to find that pointer.

```
julia> obj = @pycall numpy.reshape(numpy.arange(20), (4,5))::Any
PyObject array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

julia> array_interface = obj.__array_interface__
Dict{Any,Any} with 6 entries:
  "shape"   => (4, 5)
  "strides" => nothing
  "typestr" => "<i8"
  "data"    => (4705395216, false)
  "descr"   => Tuple{String,String}[("", "<i8")]
  "version" => 3

julia> array_interface["data"] # This is the actual pointer!
(4705395216, false)

julia> unsafe_wrap(Matrix{Int}, Ptr{Int}(array_interface["data"][1]), reverse(array_interface["shape"]))
5×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  5  10  15
 1  6  11  16
 2  7  12  17
 3  8  13  18
 4  9  14  19
```

Of course, I don't know how your python object stores its pointer.  You'll have to dig into your Python object to find that pointer yourself.